# Single MySQL query summing results between a date and having count

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a single query that would give me the total sum of occurrences of a client_id who appear only once between a certain date range.

I have the query below which returns to the total but has an error when I add date range

```
 SELECT 
COUNT(cnt)
FROM
(SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
    loans l5
GROUP BY l5.client_id
HAVING cnt < 2) AS a
```

Comment: Show the query and the error message

Comment: Table's structure please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will give you the total number of client id occurrence where its equal to 1. Just add your date logic in "where" clause

```
select count(cnt) from (
 SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM
        loans l5 where <YOUR DATE LOGIC>
    GROUP BY l5.client_id
    HAVING cnt = 1) a
```

Comment: Happy to help !!